# How to customize the Calendar View in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I have the following requirement for the OOTB Calendar Month view (in the default Calendar web part) :

1. Combine the Saturday and Sunday into a single column and show all events for both days in that column
2. Provide a way to filter by year (say, a dropdown).

I did search on the forum and I found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/f3c4d41b-367f-48a2-9733-9ac615500be5) , but the answer in this post did not give details.

I got the starting point from this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010programming/thread/edc1f5f4-beea-4186-a547-d1128181b652). As per my analysis the Calendar monthly view is rendered by the CalendarViewmonthChrome Control template. I could not find any XSL that is being used to transform the data to month view.

After looking at the source code and the application page templates for Calendar I could conclude that the Day columns Monday, Tuesday, etc. are coming from ApplicationPages:AjaxCalendarView, but I could not get any MSDN documentaion for this control.

Does anybody have any idea on how to achieve the above requirement ? Am I on the right direction of customizing the Calendar Month view via custom Control templates ? Is any javascript required ?